# Integrating Crashlytics in a multi-module project

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have an Android project with a main module plus multiple other sub-modules. I integrated Crashlytics in the project successfully, by updating the project-level build.gradle and the main module build.gradle:

Project-level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://maven.google.com'}
        maven {url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
    }
}
```

Main-module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    ...

    implementation project(':modules:sensordata:collection:ambient:module-wifinetwork')
    ...
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/rvalerio/maven' }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

build.gradle for module module-wifinetwork (similar for every module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    ...
}
```

My problem is that crash reports from the main-module are correctly sent to the firebase backend, while crash reports in other modules are not, even though they are correctly identified, because if I put this command in a class in the sub-module:

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().crash();
```

I receive the following:

```
2019-12-18 10:19:54.328 29944-30002/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog E/EventBus: Could not dispatch event: class it.unitn.disi.witmee.modules.core.systembus.model.BusObject to subscribing class class it.unitn.disi.witmee.modules.core.systembus.core.SensorlogMainBus
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=10
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashTest.indexOutOfBounds(CrashTest.java:30)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.crash(CrashlyticsCore.java:635)
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.crash(Crashlytics.java:340)
        at it.unitn.disi.witmee.modules.sensordatacollection.ambient.wifinetwork.runnables.SensorRunnable.run(SensorRunnable.java:38)
        at it.unitn.disi.witmee.modules.sensordatacollection.sensormodule.receivers.StartAllBroadcastReceiver.busEventCallback(StartAllBroadcastReceiver.java:23)
        at it.unitn.disi.witmee.modules.core.systembus.core.SensorlogMainBus.onEvent(SensorlogMainBus.java:219)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:507)
        at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:501)
        at org.greenrobot.eventbus.BackgroundPoster.run(BackgroundPoster.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Any clue why this is not working in the sub-module? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, just had to rebuild the project. So the solution is to add the following elements to the project-level build.gradle and to the main-module build.gradle, nothing to be added to individual modules build.gradle. And then clean and rebuild your project.

Project-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
    }
}
```

Main-module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    ...


repositories {
    ...
}
```